# Transfer USDT between spot and futures in Binance with ccxt python

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, binance, ccxt

```
import time
start = time.time()
exchange.sapi_post_futures_transfer({
    'asset': 'USDT',
    'amount': '10',
    'type': 2,
})
end = time.time()
```

I want to take a long position in the spot market and a short position in the future market. To do that, I have to make a USDT transfer between spot and future wallets. My question is:

Execution time of the above transfer code is around 1 second.
Except for USDT transfer between wallets, my entire code, including creating orders, takes milliseconds. Since USDT transfer takes 1 second, is there a risk that the execution of order code runs before USDT transfer so the order can not be implemented due to lack of funds? If so, what would be the best solution?

Thank you

Comment: Not sure what your strategy logic is. Why don't you transfer some funds into futures wallet before the trading signal?

Comment: Let's say that I am in full long position and I receive short signal. So I have to close all long positions, transfer USDT to future wallet and open short positions. Transferring USDT takes around 1 second. I wonder if there is a risk that execution order code(opening short positions) runs before money transfer?  If it happens there wont be enough funds to open short position.

Comment: Yes indeed there is the risk you mentioned. And nothing we can do about this except transfering some money into futures account early. But I'm still not convinced why not take long and short position both in futures market?

Comment: Due to the funding rate in Binance futures, I will open long positions in spot market. I checked the historical data and saw that people in long position pay to ones in short position most of the time. I made the backtest and effect on my results were significant.